# Is there an R equivalent to the bash command more?

Tags: r

If i want to look through a long output or variable in R, is there an equivalent to the bash command more?

Comment: more is a Unix command, not a bash command.

Comment: I usually subset the object where I want to look. myDF[1:500, ]; myDF[1500:2500, ]...

Answer (score 11):

Why not use the built-in file.show?

```
more <- function(x) {
  file <- tempfile()
  sink(file); on.exit(sink())
  print(x)
  file.show(file, delete.file = T)
}

more(mtcars)
more(more)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use ESS you get to scroll through the R output buffer, and of course search etc as well, at your leisure.  Just saying...

Answer (score 3):

For those of us who don't want to use Emacs... ;-) @ Dirk

```
more <- function(x, n=6) {
  i <- 1
  while(i <= length(x)) {
    j <- min(length(x),i+n-1)
    print(x[i:j])
    i <- i+n
    if(i <= length(x)) readline()
  }
}
```

This isn't going to be pretty on all objects.  It's just an example of a default method.  You would need to write methods for `matrix`, `data.frame`, etc.

Comment: Sure, you can always re-invent your own operating system :)

Comment: Just to note: to use this with a data.frame or matrix, you need to replace `length` with `nrow`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but it should be easy to create.  Just look for user input with `readline("\nType  <Return> to go to the next page : ")` and recursively cycle through the object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my trick: I use `screen` or `byobu` in Linux, and then F7 which allows me to scroll back and forth through whatever I want.  Then again, I rarely use `more` in bash, when I get so much more from `less`.  ;-)  `less` is more than `more`.  Very punny.

Another nice multi-platform option is RStudio, which allows you to scroll back and forth with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely scroll through a whole data set in R. When I do I tend to push it to a CSV then use a spreadsheet to peruse it. For just looking at the output in short chunks I use `head()` or `tail()`

I have, of course, been asked by my coworkers if I `tail(head))` (yes, head in tail jokes never get old to me)

If you want to look at only a vector, you could do this:

```
system("more", input=as.character(rnorm(1000)))
```

This doesn't work well with data frames or matrices because the `input` param needs a character vector.

**edit**

for data frames and matrices you could bring together my "export to CSV" and the command line `more` function like this:

```
myDF <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1000), b=rnorm(1000))

more <- function(dataFrame) {
  myTempFile <- tempfile()
  write.csv(dataFrame, file=myTempFile, row.names = F)
  system(paste("more", myTempFile))
}

more(myDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use sytem `more`:

```
more<-function(x){
    tempfile()->fn;
    sink(fn);print(x);sink();
    system(sprintf('more %s',fn));
    system(sprintf('rm %s',fn));
}
```

...or `less` which I like because I does not mess the terminal:

```
less<-function(x){
    tempfile()->fn;
    sink(fn);print(x);sink();
    system(sprintf('less %s',fn));
    system(sprintf('rm %s',fn));
}
```

Both are for *nixes; for Windows, I think it is better to make something based on `edit` (and string connections).